# heuristically find how different a set of files are

Tags: shell, ubuntu, diff

I am having a large number of output files produced by repeated runs of a test suite and would like to see, approximately, how different they are. Ideally they should all be identical (indicating a fully reproducible test) or nearly identical (e.g. if timestamps are present). So I am looking for a script like:

```
show-greatest-diff /path/to/files/*.out
```

So, if 100 *.out files are present the script should `diff` them all against each other and perhaps produce the maximum number of lines / characters that any pair amongst them differ (and maybe identify the most different pair) or just print the `diff` output of the pair that differs the most or produce some other heuristically helpful output.

The solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1075708/274677) is not appropriate for my use case due to the large number of files.

Comment: Are these plaintext files?

Comment: @Oli, yes plaintext files.

Comment: Why diff against all other files in the directory, creating a matrix of diffs? Shouldn't you have a benchmark "correct" output file that all there can be diffed against? A matrix implies that you don't know which is correct, and are going to pick one of the central items in the matrix post facto, purely because it is least different from all the others, which implies that you don't know what your goal looks like until you see it. (See [Texas sharpshooter fallacy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texas_sharpshooter).)

Comment: @WarrenYoung your point is valid for this particular use case. Still, such a quick-n-dirty heuristic would still be useful for this and other use cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about something like

```
mostdifs=-1;
for f1 in path/to/files/*.out; do 
    for f2 in path/to/files/*.out; do 
        difs=$(diff "$f1" "$f2" | wc -l); 
        [ "$difs" -gt "$mostdifs" ] && mostdifs=$difs && mostdif="$f1 : $f2";
    done 
done 
echo "$mostdif"
```

This is very simplistic, you could improve it by testing whether `$f1` is the same file as `$f2` and by various other tweaks but if we're talking about a few hundred text files, it will run in seconds so the extra complexity might not be worth it.

The idea is to run `diff` on each pair of files and look at the number of lines returned. If that number is greater than the current greatest, save the file names.

Comment: `[[ > ]]` is strings comparison. Use `(( difs > mostdifs ))` for number comparison.

Comment: `(( "$difs" > "$mostdifs" ))` doesn't work in `zsh`. Quotes don't make sense here. `[ "$difs" -gt "$mostdiffs" ]` (Bourne/Csh/POSIX), or `(( difs > mostdifs ))` (ksh, zsh, bash).

Comment: @StephaneChazelas thanks, I was wondering about the quotes, I didn't think they were necessary but copied directly from the [official docs](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html). I settled on `[ "$difs" -gt "$mostdifs" ] ` which seems to be the safest.

Comment: Not sure why they use quotes (that's no official doc, that's the ABS). Note that it does not make any difference in `a=4 b='1|2' bash -c '(( $a < $b ))'`  vs `a=4 b='1|2' bash -c '(( "$a" < "$b" ))'`. You need `(( a < b ))` to compare the a and b arithmetic expressions (or `(( ($a) < ($b) ))`)

Comment: @StephaneChazelas no idea either. The only reason I can think of would be to avoid splitting on `$IFS` but that should be irrelevant here. And no, you're right, not "official" but still quite authoritative. I guess they just did it out of habit.

Comment: the ABS is not exactly praised among the bash afficionados... I would not qualify it as authoritative at all.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf oh? I admit I have not looked into it in any depth but it has served me well.